# Button click call/execute a batch file C#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm using 'VScode' and attempting to create a button in my `'.cshtml'` file that calls a function from my `.cshtml.cs` file that when clicked will execute a batch file. The button appears but when I click on it. Nothing seems to happen. I'm positive the batch file works

Here are the two files I've used:

First file
[Testing.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Y5d.png)

```
@page
@model QASite.Pages.TestingModel
@{
    <h1>Crosstab</h1>
    <div>
        <button input type="submit" onclick="Button_click()"> 
            SCharacters</button>
    </div>
   

}
```

Second file
[Testing.cshtml.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZmOX.png)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Testing.cshtml;

namespace QASite.Pages
{
    public class TestingModel : PageModel
    {
        //public object Controls { get; private set; }



        public void Button_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //private TestingModel()
            //{

            //}
            string filename = `"C:\\Users\\`SIUtility`\\specialCharactersInExports2019";`
            string v = $"/k \"{filename}\"";
            string parameters = v;
            Process.Start("`cmd`", parameters);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: its going to start the code on your server

Comment: Please include your code _as text_ (formatted as `code`), not as a link to a picture

Comment: So, like @DanielA.White pointed out, that code (the button handler) is running on the server, as a result, the batch file will run there. Web pages can't normally run code on the client (think about it, I could hit your web page and you could run any batch file on my machine - yikes). Browsers run code in a tight _sandbox_; they can play on my machine, but only within that sandbox (which prevents the arbitrary of possibly malicious code)

Comment: This is for a internal server and the site is intranet. Anyone that has access to the site will also have the inherent permissions to run the batch files on the server